# Is it possible to use an operator within a function that is returning an operator, in Airflow?

Tags: airflow, airflow-taskflow

I am currently writing/creating an external table in [databricks](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-external-tables.html).

To do so, I am using the [DatabricksSqlOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-databricks/stable/operators/sql.html).

I have a function that returns this Dbks Operator with all the needed details in it.

```
@dag(...)
.
.
.
def create_external():
    return DatabricksSqlOperator(...)
```

However, to improve the quality of the code, I want to query the schema table in dbks before creating the external table (to check for schema changes).

I would like to know if it would be possible to use an operator inside the same function, or if it has to be an extra "task" in my DAG. Since its an intermediate task, it will be very ugly to have everywhere.

```
@dag(...)
.
.
.
def create_external():

    query_result = DatabricksSqlOperator(...)
    if query_result:
        queries= [query1, query2]
    else:
        queries= [query1]

    return DatabricksSqlOperator(query=queries)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be a separate task plus a branch operator that are aligned in a sequence like this:

```
query1 >> test_query >> branch >> query2
```

If it is a repeating pattern you can wrap it in a [task group](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dags.html#taskgroups):

```py
def create_external():
    def decide(**kwargs):
        result = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='test')
        return 'query2' if result == "xxx" else None  # adjust the test

    @task_group()
    def databricks_group():
        query1 = DatabricksSqlOperator(...)
        test_query = DatabricksSqlOperator(...)
        branch = BranchPythonOperator(
            task_id='branch',
            provide_context=True,
            python_callable=decide
        )
        query2 = DatabricksSqlOperator(...)

    return databricks_group()
```

Notes:

- Beware of `trigger_rule` traps in pipelines containing branches (read [here](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-branch-operator))
- If you look into [`BranchSqlOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/fcd6160f7e8718aae332ed638f49501d5a66de47/airflow/providers/common/sql/operators/sql.py#L1110) and [`DatabricksSqlOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/fcd6160f7e8718aae332ed638f49501d5a66de47/airflow/providers/databricks/operators/databricks_sql.py#L42C41-L42C41) you might be able to define something like `BranchDatabricksSqlOperator` that would allow to have `test_query` and `branch` as a single task

Comment: Thank you so much for the valuable answer. :) 
One more question, would it be possible to use the hook on its own? I did some reading and it seems like hooks are of potential use for my case? 
Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, you can always use a hook as a standalone class...

Comment: Perfect will test soon, both methods and either submit an answer or lock yours as an answer :) ! Thank you again

Comment: i ended up opting for a taskflow api @task, less complex, easier way to communicate xcoms ...